# Instagram JSON export. Pivot SubArray with OPENJSON

Tags: json, t-sql, instagram

I just received my like data from Instragram in a file with .json extension.

```
{"media_likes": [["2019-12-10T17:49:02", "feojo"], 
                 ["2019-12-10T14:11:53", "sollylun"],
                 ["2016-02-16T17:05:43", "ser_mart"]], 
"comment_likes":[["2019-11-28T18:05:04", "kerslyrikatel"], 
                 ["2019-11-28T18:05:03", "jakar"],
                 ["2019-12-10T14:11:53", "sollylun"]]}
```

I can return the subarrays in a value column but don't know who to pivot those arrays into 'date' and 'user' columns:

```
   DECLARE @JSON1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @JSON1 = '{
                     "media_likes": [
                                     ["2019-12-10T17:49:02", "feonaleejones"], 
                                     ["2019-12-10T14:11:53", "sollyluna021"],
                                     ["2016-02-16T17:05:43", "serene_martin"]
                                    ], 
                      "comment_likes":[
                                      ["2019-11-28T18:05:04", "kerstinslyrikatelier"], 
                                      ["2019-11-28T18:05:03", "jan.kart"],
                                      ["2019-12-10T14:11:53", "sollyluna021"]
                                      ]
                      }'

SELECT [key],value 
  FROM OPENJSON(@JSON1,'$.media_likes') 

key value
0   ["2019-12-10T17:49:02", "feonaleejones"]
1   ["2019-12-10T14:11:53", "sollyluna021"]
2   ["2016-02-16T17:05:43", "serene_martin"]
```

How to pivot the two set array in value?

John

Comment: I see now the export uses arrays.

Comment: So I figured out my structure is an array and it's pretty common I guess. So I'm getting close.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   DECLARE @JSON1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @JSON1 = '{
                     "media_likes": [
                                     ["2019-12-10T17:49:02", "feonaleejones"], 
                                     ["2019-12-10T14:11:53", "sollyluna021"],
                                     ["2016-02-16T17:05:43", "serene_martin"]
                                    ], 
                      "comment_likes":[
                                      ["2019-11-28T18:05:04", "kerstinslyrikatelier"], 
                                      ["2019-11-28T18:05:03", "jan.kart"],
                                      ["2019-12-10T14:11:53", "sollyluna021"]
                                      ]
                      }'

SELECT likedate,userlike 
  FROM OPENJSON(@JSON1,'$.media_likes') 
  WITH (
       likedate datetime '$[0]',
       userlike varchar(128) '$[1]'
       )
```